# Any free web analytics/tracking services without JavaScript?

Tags: tracking, analytics

Is there any free web analytics/tracking service that can work without JavaScript on client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics has a [document](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/) with server-side code snippets in several languages. It says it's for mobile use, but the actually important bit is that it's for situations where the browser may not support Javascript.

As for other services, a lot of their code comes in this general format:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[Javascript URL]"></script>
<noscript>
    <a href="[http://example.com]"><img src="[URL for tracking pixel]"/></a>
</noscript>
```

Just rip out and use *only* the stuff inside the noscript tag.
[Site Meter](http://www.sitemeter.com/) provides it right on the same  page as the usual JS snippet.

The data you collect will be limited, though, compared to what the JS can get you.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure histats.com to do so !

Get an account and create an hidden tracker.

Now click the no Javascript tag and paste it onto your website !

[image]

Comment: This site looks highly non-professional, even password at registration is shown in plain text :-/

Comment: it's good i use it ... your call .. i see that you want it for Google SItes :)